# Basis coefficients in strong convergence of sequence in Hilbert space

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, hilbert-spaces

Let $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}\subset H$ be a basis of a Hilbert space which is **not necessarily orthogonal**, and a sequence $x_n\in H$ such that:
$$x_n=\sum_{i\in I}{\alpha_n^iv_i}$$
Now, assume that $x_n\to x$ (strongly convergence) and:
$$x=\sum_{i\in I}{\alpha^iv_i}$$
Is it true that $\alpha_n^i\to \alpha^i$ for every $i\in I$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Hilbert space $\ell^2$ and let $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be the canonical vectors.

Denote $e = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n e_n$ and let $B$ be an algebraic basis for $\ell^2$ containing the linearly independent set $S = \{e_n : n\in \Bbb{N}\} \cup \{e\}$.

Consider
$$x_n := \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k e_k = \sum_{b \in B} \alpha_n^b b, \quad \alpha_n^b = \begin{cases}
\frac1k, &\text{if $b = e_k$ with $1 \le k \le n$}, \\
0, &\text{if $b = e_k$ with $k > n$}, \\
0, &\text{if $b = e$}, \\
0, &\text{if $b \in B\setminus S$}, \\
\end{cases} $$
$$x := \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k e_k = e = \sum_{b \in B} \alpha^b b, \quad \alpha^b = \begin{cases}
0, &\text{if $b = e_k$ with $k\in\Bbb{N}$}, \\
1, &\text{if $b = e$}, \\
0, &\text{if $b \in B\setminus S$}, \\
\end{cases} $$

Then $x_n \to x$ strongly in $\ell^2$ but
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \alpha^b_n = \begin{cases}
\frac1k, &\text{if $b = e_k$ with $k\in\Bbb{N}$}, \\
0, &\text{if $b = e$}, \\
0, &\text{if $b \in B\setminus S$}, \\
\end{cases} \ne \alpha_b.$$

Comment: This is not a good example because $\alpha_n^m=\begin{cases}0\text{ if }n<m\\\frac{1}{m}\text{ if }n\ge m\end{cases}$ and it is clear that $\lim_{m\to \infty}{\alpha_n^m}=\frac{1}{m}=\alpha^m$

Comment: If you are denoting $x_n = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \alpha_n^m e_m$ then $$\alpha_{n}^m = \begin{cases} \frac1m, \text{ if $m \le n$} \\ 0, \text{ if $m > n$} \end{cases}.$$
 It is true that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \alpha_n^m =\frac1m$, and that $x = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac1m e_m$, but this is not a linear combination in terms of the basis $B$. We want $$x = \sum_{b \in B} \alpha_b b$$
where at most finitely many $\alpha_b$ are nonzero. This is the interpretation you want when dealing with algebraic bases.

Comment: @SagiShadur Have a look now, I added some details.